# Can we take input in array (a1,a2) in this way?

Tags: c++, arrays, input

Suppose if we are having two integer array `a1[2]` and `a2[2]` and we want to take input so what we generally do is

```
int a1[2],a2[2];
int i;
cout<<"Enter values in array a1\n";
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    cin>>a1[i];       // Taking input in a1 separatly using loop
}
cout<<"Enter values in array a2\n";
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    cin>>a2[i];      // Taking input in a2 separatly using loop
}
```

But can we do something like this to minimize using cin statements in code ..

```
for(j=1;j<3;j++)   // Loop for taking input in a(j) array , value of j will be 1 first time so that input will be in array a1
{
    cout<<"Enter values in array a"<<j<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        cin>>a(j)[i];   // Can we do something like this so that we can take input using a loop inside loop
    }
}
```

I don't know what should be the correct question title so anyone who wants to edit question title can do.

Comment: Yes, there's `std::map` to support such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like the following?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 2;
    int a1[N];
    int a2[N];
    size_t j = 1;

    for ( auto &r : { std::ref( a1 ), std::ref( a2 ) } )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter values in array a" << j++ << ": ";
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        {
            std::cin >> r.get()[i];
        }
    }        

    for ( auto &r : { std::ref( a1 ), std::ref( a2 ) } )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) std::cout << r.get()[i] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        
}
```

If to enter

```
1 2 3 4
```

then the output will look like

```
Enter values in array a1: 1 2
Enter values in array a2: 3 4
1 2 
3 4
```

Using this approach you can use more than only two arrays. For example

```
    const size_t N = 2;
    int a1[N];
    int a2[N];
    int a3[N];
    int a4[N];
    size_t j = 1;

    for ( auto &r : { std::ref( a1 ), std::ref( a2 ), std::ref( a3 ), std::ref( a4 ) } )
    //...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep 2 separate arrays, you can do the following:

```
for(j=1;j<=2;j++)   // Loop for taking input in a(j) array , value of j will be 1 first time so that input will be in array a1
{
    cout<<"Enter values in array a"<<j<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        cin>>(j == 1 ? a1[i] : a2[i]);
    }
}
```

If it's no problem for you to have 1 array, you can do the following using 2-dimensional array:

```
int a[2][2]
for(int i=0; i<=1; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter values for a[" << i << "][j]" << endl;
    for(int j=0; j<=1; j++)
    {
        cin >> a[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here a1 and a2 are array variable names. i doubt if you can do that. 
what I am thinking we can do  to address you point is something like

1. construct a cpp statement string
2. [execute string as cpp code inside program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841511/execute-c-from-string-variable)
   I don't feel doing it is straightforward though