# C++ can you make a code that executes user input as a command?

Tags: c++

Hi I have been trying to make a program that will ask for the users input and whatever the user types it will execute it as a command. Sort of like CMD

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string A;
int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i > -1; ++i){
        cout << "Command: ";
        cin >> A;

        // Here Would Be The Code

        cout << "Command Executed!";
    }
}
```

Here is what i imagine a possible output (if it worked)

```
Command: cout << "Test";
Test
Command Executed!
```

Comment: btw this is my first post so tell me if im doing anything wrong (or right).

Comment: You mean with CMD, a c++ code or a shell command?

Comment: @Dosisod Welcome to stackoverflow! In my opinion, your question is basically same as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841511/execute-c-from-string-variable) that already has been answered.

Comment: ok thanks i actually saw that right after i posted this XD.

Comment: I'd think this though if I were you. First thing I'd do with this is paste in a low-level hard disk format routine. Second thing I'd do is laugh evilly whilst hitting enter.

Answer (score -5):

You can use the system function.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/

```
system("command")
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he's looking for. It looks like he wants to execute C++ function calls.

Comment: So why not ask him to clarify? Also he could create a case statement with his 'commands' and execute corresponding functions.