# C++ Simple Calculator (no if, Switch, Case, and its kind)

Tags: c++, calculator

I tried to make Simple calculator. There are 3 inputs :

1. number 1
2. number 2
3. operators

The operator is selected using number :

`1 = '+'`
 `2 = '-'`
 `3 = '*'`
 `4 = '/'`

Example :
Number1 = 1, number 2 = 1, operator = 1, then the equation goes 1 + 1 = 2.

I didn't know how to make this equation possible. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

**note : not using `array` or `string`, not using `case`, not using `switch`, not using `if`, `while`, `for`.*

Here's my code, but it's not yet completed and I need to change the operator selector.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){

    int a, b, c, hasil;

    cout << "Masukkan Bilangan 1 : ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Masukkan Bilangan 2 : ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Masukkan Operator ['(0 = +)' , '(1 = -)' , '(2 = *)', '(3 = /)' ] : ";
    cin >> c;

    hasil = a + (c * -2 + 1 )* b;
    cout << "Hasilnya = " << hasil;
}
```

Comment: how do you plan on selecting your operator without using any kind of check?

Comment: If ternary `?:` is allowed, then `hasil = c==0 ? a+b : c==1 ? a-b : c==2 ? a*b : a/b;`

Comment: @UnholySheep By using math, at my code you can try use the number 0 to  + the number1 and number 2.

Comment: Something like this perhaps: `hasil = (a+b)*(c==0) + (a-b)*(c==1) + (a*b)*(c==2) + (a/b)*(c==3);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik no, its not allowed because it's same as the if and else

Comment: Which of the two versions I suggested is not allowed?

Comment: The first one hasil = c==0 ? a+b : c==1 ? a-b : c==2 ? a*b : a/b; @IgorTandetnik

Comment: if igor isn't right then maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841511/execute-c-from-string-variable essentially what you are asking to branch on certain conditions using none of the language features that allow branching, actually strings aren't even allowed so even executing c code from string wouldn't work

Comment: Is this homework? Who is setting these "don't use this, don't use that" conditions?

Comment: Yes, this is my homework. I need help, my code only work if the operator number is 0 and 1.  @n.m.

Comment: instead of `int(*operators)(int, int)[]`, use `std::map<char, int(*)(int, int)> operators` or `boost::bimap<char, int(*)(int, int)> operators` or whatever, until you come across a collection library not forbidden?

Comment: Since it's homework, I cannot do it for you, but you probably want to explore properties of the `==` operator. What could its result possibly be? Can you use it in a more complex expression?

Comment: @UnholySheep "no check" is actually easy, as long as you can use array-like dictionary, but the OP can't use even that, and then you must just create formula which has desired results. It's common technique when you want to produce branch-less machine code due to performance or cryptographic reasons (to maintain fast and/or constant speed of execution). The requirement of "division" operator makes this "unreal", as it introduces many problems and poor performance, but remaining parts of Q looks almost exactly as requirements for pixel shader for some special effects (example from real world).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you basically have to calculate all four of them at the same time (warning, "1+0" will then crash, because it will divide by zero during calculation, even if "+" operation was chosen), and filter out the unneeded ones.

To filter out unneeded ones you need to turn `c` into one of the four value sets:

```
c==1: [1, 0, 0, 0]
c==2: [0, 1, 0, 0]
c==3: [0, 0, 1, 0]
c==4: [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Let's call those inner four values c<sub>i</sub>, i=1..4

c<sub>1</sub> = ((c-2) * (c-3) * (c-4)) / -6;
c<sub>2</sub> = ((c-1) * (c-3) * (c-4)) / 2;
c<sub>3</sub> = ((c-1) * (c-2) * (c-4)) / -2;
c<sub>4</sub> = ((c-1) * (c-2) * (c-3)) / 6;

Then:

result = c<sub>1</sub> * (a+b) + c<sub>2</sub> * (a-b) + c<sub>3</sub> * (a*b) + c<sub>4</sub> * (a/b);

---

This is "pure math" solution, without exploiting C++ `bool` implicit conversion to 0/1, which would be better in production code, but I think it's a bit "cheating" in this exercise, that's why I'm calculating the 0/1 coefficients without the `bool` conversions in such complex manner by using the polynomials.

---

Few updates, to steer away from "pure math" a bit toward something more practical.

- unwanted division by zero solution: instead of (a/b) you can calculate (a/(b|(c<sub>4</sub>-1))) (for c<sub>4</sub> being 0 or 1). This will make the divisor equal to `-1` whenever the c<sub>4</sub> is zero, so it will neutralise "division by zero" for inputs like "a = 1, b = 0, c = 1" (i.e. "1+0"), and the division by zero may happen only when operation "division" is selected and b == 0.
- if you will flip c<sub>i</sub> values from [0, 1] to [0, -1] (just change sign of the fixed constants at the final normalizing division), and everything is `int`, then you can replace the c<sub>i</sub> multiplications in final formula with bitwise `AND` like: result = (c<sub>1</sub> & (a+b)) + (c<sub>2</sub> & (a-b)) + (c<sub>3</sub> & (a*b)) + (c<sub>4</sub> & (a/b)); - which will be marginally faster on modern CPU (and considerably faster on historic CPU). {then of course the division by zero fix has to be flipped too => b|(-1-c<sub>4</sub>)}

note: uh, I aimed for -1 for the division fix, thinking about making whole division going to 0 in unsigned math for most of the inputs, then I figured out this is signed `int` and overall it makes little sense, but I kept `-1` as target value, while anything non-zero will work, even simple `1`. And the bitwise `AND` works only on platforms where negative integers are implemented by two's complement logic, so `-1` is full bitmask then (as you didn't specify platform, this may break on some weird ones... the original answer with multiplication will work even on those).

Comment: Wow!! This is just what i needed!, Thank for your help, really appreciate itt!! :D

Comment: @JoseIshak just let me know, if you got the idea behind it (creating four polynomials, with roots being the unwanted `c` values, so each polynomial will result into zero for any unwanted `c` and only for the wanted one (non-root) some fixed value is result, which is normalized to +1).

Comment: Yess, i got the idea, your answer is very clear. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 3):

You can use different functions for the different operators and then select them by using the "c" value as the index to a table of functions.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef int (*OperatorFunction)(int a, int b);

static int OperatorPlus(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

static int OperatorMinus(int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;
}

static int OperatorMultiply(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}

static int OperatorDivide(int a, int b)
{
    return a / b;
}

OperatorFunction operators[] = { OperatorPlus, OperatorMinus, OperatorMultiply, OperatorDivide };

int main()
{

    int a, b, c, hasil;

    cout << "Masukkan Bilangan 1 : ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Masukkan Bilangan 2 : ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Masukkan Operator ['(0 = +)' , '(1 = -)' , '(2 = *)', '(3 = /)' ] : ";
    cin >> c;

    hasil = operators[c](a, b);

    cout << "Hasilnya = " << hasil << "\n";
}
```

Comment: well, just saw your comment saying not using an array, so this solution is not valid then

Comment: But thanks for your help! maybe i will need it soon :)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of with this assignment is to make use of that in C++ there's an implicit conversion between boolean type and integer. To take advantage of it you can do :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){

    int a, b, c, hasil;

    cout << "Masukkan Bilangan 1 : ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Masukkan Bilangan 2 : ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Masukkan Operator ['(0 = +)' , '(1 = -)' , '(2 = *)', '(3 = /)' ] : ";
    cin >> c;

    // if your input is a=10, b=5, c=0 :
    // a + b == 15
    // !c == 1
    // 15 * 1 == 15
    // a - b == 5
    // !(c - 1) == !(0 - 1) == 0
    // 5 * 0 == 0
    // and so on...

    hasil = ((a + b) * !c) + ((a - b) * !(c - 1)) + ((a * b) * !(c - 2)) + ((a / b) * !(c - 3));

    cout << "Hasilnya = " << hasil;
}
```

*explanation :*

If your `c` input is `0` and you're doing `!c` it will return `1` as a `int` representation of `TRUE` but then for each other value eg. 3 it will return `0` as a `int` representation of `FALSE`. This is then multiplied by the calculated value of each possible operator and return either calculated value or `0` ( because `0 * 99 == 0` ).

[Try this online](http://cpp.sh/3t3t)

Comment: C++ does have a Boolean type - it's called `bool` (but the language rules do allow implicit conversion between Boolean and numeric values)

Comment: @UnholySheep Got confused with it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks for  your help! Really appreciate it!