# How to output a variable stored in another variable

Tags: c++

So here's my code at the moment:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string x = "_one";
    int sound_one = 7;
    int sound_two = 8; 
    cout << ("sound") + x;
}
```

However when I run the code, it outputs 'sound_one' instead of '7'. How do I get it to output the variable sound_one instead of just 'sound_one'? Also, I need it so I can change x to different things (eg '_two') so it will then output sound_two instead. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot do that in C++. C++ does not work this way. What is the real problem you're trying to solve? No, not the one about using variables this way, but the real problem to which you believe the solution involves using variables this way so that's what you're asking about. If you explain what the real problem is, I'm sure there's a C++ solution for that. But this isn't it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143120/convert-string-to-variable-name-or-variable-type may be a  hashmap could solve your problem of keeping integer values against string keys, if it is what you are after

Comment: Does this answer your question? [execute C++ from String variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841511/execute-c-from-string-variable)

Comment: C++ doesn't knows how to count alphabetically: One, Two, Three, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ is not a *reflective* language in the sense that you can acquire a variable name at runtime (variable names are normally compiled out of the program). You can use `std::map` though to achieve your immediate aim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
 
int main() {
    using std::literals::string_literals::operator""s;

    std::string x = "_one";
    std::map<std::string, int> data;
    data["sound_one"] = 7;
    data["sound_two"] = 8;
    std::cout << data["sound"s + x];
}
```

Note the notation `"sound"s`: the suffixed `s` denotes a `std::string` *user defined literal*.

Comment: I don't think the `s` suffix will work if we don't do `using` on some `namespace`. This code, as it is, does not compile.

Comment: @Fureeish: If I had a dollar for every time I'd slipped that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't a variable from a string in this way. A work around is to use if/switch statements until the variable name is matched and then print it:

```
if(x == "_one") {
   cout << sound_one;
}
else if(x == "_two") {
   cout << sound_two;
}
else {
   cout << "no match";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in C++. You can use a map as shown in another answer, but I feel like what you really need is an array:

```
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int data[] { 7, 8 };
    std::cout << std::format("data[{}] = {}\n", 0, data[0]);
}
```

Arrays are usually better for such simple ordered sequences.